# AWS API gateway binary media type not mapping correctly

Tags: terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I wanted to use AWS api gateway for some pdf related lambda functions -- upload the pdf and save it to S3, at the same time update the record. I've made it work the day before but my gateway stop working since yesterday.

It cannot map content-type with integration template correctly and in the end there is no pdf data passed to my lambda.

The api setting has allowed application/pdf and there is mapping template in it. I've spent a whole trying to fix it but no luck. Thanks for you help and time.

My terraform script here:

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "api_gateway" {
name               = "api_gateway"
description        = "API Gateway"
binary_media_types = \["application/pdf"\]
endpoint_configuration {
types = \["REGIONAL"\]
}
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_account" "infofusion" {
cloudwatch_role_arn = aws_iam_role.cloudwatch.arn
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role" {
statement {
effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["apigateway.amazonaws.com"]
    }
    
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

}
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "cloudwatch" {
name               = "api_gateway_cloudwatch_global"
assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "cloudwatch" {
statement {
effect = "Allow"

    actions = [
      "logs:CreateLogGroup",
      "logs:CreateLogStream",
      "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
      "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
      "logs:PutLogEvents",
      "logs:GetLogEvents",
      "logs:FilterLogEvents"
    ]
    
    resources = ["*"]

}
}
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "cloudwatch" {
name   = "default"
role   = aws_iam_role.cloudwatch.id
policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.cloudwatch.json
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_authorizer" "cognito" {
name            = "cognito"
rest_api_id     = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.id
type            = "COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
identity_source = "method.request.header.Authorization"
provider_arns   = \[aws_cognito_user_pool.user_pool.arn\]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "pdf" {
parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.root_resource_id
path_part   = "pdf"
rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.id
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "upload_pdf" {
rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.id
resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.pdf.id
request_parameters = {
"method.request.querystring.pdfName"   = true
"method.request.querystring.projectId" = true
}
http_method   = "PUT"
authorization = "COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
authorizer_id = aws_api_gateway_authorizer.cognito.id
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "upload_pdf" {
rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.id
resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.pdf.id
http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.upload_pdf.http_method
integration_http_method = "POST"
type                    = "AWS"
uri                     = aws_lambda_function.manage_pdf.invoke_arn
request_parameters = {
"integration.request.querystring.pdfName"   = "method.request.querystring.pdfName"
"integration.request.querystring.projectId" = "method.request.querystring.projectId"
}
passthrough_behavior = "WHEN_NO_MATCH"
request_templates = {
\# "application/pdf" = file("${path.module}/resource/apigateway/pdf_upload_mapping_template.vt")
\# I have a more sophisticated vt but at the moment I just want to get the body first
"application/pdf" = \<\<-EOT
{
"data": "$input.body"
}
EOT
}
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "pdf_lambda_permission" {
statement_id  = "AllowAPIInvokeManagePdf"
action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
function_name = aws_lambda_function.manage_pdf.function_name
principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.execution_arn}/*/*". # one doc in tf said /\* and this other /*/*, both stop working
}
```